# Reinstall Joomla failed

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.6, upgrade

I was trying to update my Joomla core to the latest 3.6.5 version, but the update failed due to space restrictions on the hosting environment.

Now, when I try to check for updates I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred 1017 Can't find file: '#__updates' (errno: 2) SQL=SELECT DISTINCT update_site_id FROM #__updates WHERE 'update_site_id' IN ( SELECT update_site_id FROM #__update_sites WHERE 'last_check_timestamp' IS NULL OR 'last_check_timestamp' <= '1481695762')
```

Is there a way to flush the error and re-try the update or do I have to manually apply the update?

Comment: Did you try to log in to your Joomla! Administrator panel and go to Extensions → Manage → Database and select the Fix button on the top left?

Comment: So, I didn't see the option for the fix database, I was only given an error at the database page. Apparently what happened was that the hosting account was over its data limit, which prevented the entire update from downloading causing an incomplete install.

Comment: OK, i would suggest checking your hosting account for the largest files and see if you can back those up offsite and remove them from your account to free up space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach for you will be to manually update Joomla!. You can do this by following these steps:

### Before updating, always take a backup and don’t forget to test it.

1. Download the update package from https://www.joomla.org/download.html
2. Extract the download package on your computer
3. Using your favorite FTP software, upload the folders and files at the root of the website or in the folder where your Joomla! installation is located. (**NOTE:** If you are using [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), click on "Replace" for all, if you are using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php), click on upload and then allow override for all. The FTP software will overwrite the existing files and add the new ones.)
4. Log in to your Joomla! Administrator panel and go to **Extensions → Manage → Database** and select the **Fix** button on the top left.
5. Go within the manage section to Discover menu item in the left menu and click the **Discover** button. Select only the **Joomla! CORE extensions** shown in the list and click the **Install** button. **(NOTE: do not select installation for the 3rd party extensions you may have installed)**.
6. In the main menu of your administrator panel, go to **System → Clear Cache** and if any rows are shown, select them and click the **Delete** button at the top left.

---

If you are coming **directly from 3.6.4**, there is a very small patch file that you can extract and upload (instead of the full 3.6.5 update package):
https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla3/3-6-5/joomla_3-6-4_to_3-6-5-stable-patch_package-zip?format=zip

---

Sources: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5, https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla3/3-6-5

Comment: I borked the install, but this should have worked. user error